# JavaFX opening up a dialog with all the fields visible

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to find a way to open a "complex" dialog in javafx with all the fields visible. This is the form in scenebuilder:

[image: Scenebuilder form]

And this is the fxml for the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="cartsan.desktop.controller.fatturazione.fxml.DocumentoFatturazioneDialogController">
    <ComboBox fx:id="cbTipologiaFattura" promptText="Tipologia documento" />
    <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefViewportHeight="800.0">
        <GridPane hgap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" vgap="10.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
            </rowConstraints>
            <Label text="Dati documento" />
            <VBox fx:id="vBoxNumero" spacing="10.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                <Label text="Numero">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" spacing="10.0">
                    <TextField fx:id="tfNumero" />
                    <Button fx:id="btnCalcolaNumeroFattura" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCalcolaNumeroFattura">
                        <graphic>
                            <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#009688" glyphName="CALCULATOR" size="20" />
                        </graphic>
                        <tooltip>
                            <Tooltip text="Calcola numero fattura" />
                        </tooltip>
                    </Button>
                </HBox>
            </VBox>
            <HBox spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                <TextField fx:id="tfSezionale" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
                <Button fx:id="btnSezionali" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onMostraSezionali">
                    <graphic>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#009688" glyphName="LIGHTBULB_ALT" size="20" />
                    </graphic>
                    <tooltip>
                        <Tooltip fx:id="ttElencoDocumenti" />
                    </tooltip>
                </Button>
            </HBox>
            <Label text="Data" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Riferimento" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Ragione sociale" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <DatePicker fx:id="dpData" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfRiferimento" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <VBox fx:id="vBoxBolloSplitPayment" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                <Label text="Bollo">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <HBox spacing="10.0">
                    <CheckBox fx:id="ckBollo">
                        <HBox.margin>
                            <Insets />
                        </HBox.margin>
                    </CheckBox>
                    <TextField fx:id="tfBollo" promptText="€" />
                    <CheckBox fx:id="ckSplitPayment" text="Split payment" />
                </HBox>
            </VBox>
            <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowSpan="9" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label text="Dati emittente" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="cbEmittente" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfRagioneSociale" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label text="Indirizzo" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Contatti" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="tfIndirizzo" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfContatti" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Label text="Partita IVA" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Codice fiscale" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="tfPartitaIva" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfCodiceFiscale" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
         <TextField fx:id="tfRitenuta" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <GridPane fx:id="gpDatiPagamento" hgap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" vgap="10.0" GridPane.columnSpan="5" GridPane.rowIndex="9">
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    <ColumnConstraints />
               <ColumnConstraints />
                    <ColumnConstraints />
               <ColumnConstraints />
               <ColumnConstraints />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints />
                    <RowConstraints />
                    <RowConstraints />
                    <RowConstraints />
                    <RowConstraints />
                    <RowConstraints />
               <RowConstraints />
                </rowConstraints>
                <HBox GridPane.columnSpan="6">
                    <Label text="Dati pagamento" />
                    <Separator prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                </HBox>
                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="Tipo pagamento" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="Intestatario" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <Button fx:id="btnScadenze" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onShowScadenzePagamento" text="Scadenze pagamento" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <ComboBox fx:id="cbTipoPagamento" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfIntestatario" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="IBAN" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="SWIFT" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="tfIBAN" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfSWIFT" maxWidth="80.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="ABI" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="CAB" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="11.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="tfABI" maxWidth="80.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                <TextField fx:id="tfCAB" maxWidth="80.0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                <Button fx:id="btnCalcolaDaIBAN" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCalcolaAbiCab" text="Calcola da IBAN" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                    <graphic>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="CALCULATOR" />
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="btnCopia" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickCopiaDatiDitta" text="Copia i dati pagamento della ditta" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label fx:id="lblABIRiba" minWidth="-Infinity" text="ABI Riba" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <font>
                  <Font size="11.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="lblCABRiba" minWidth="-Infinity" text="CAB Riba" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <font>
                  <Font size="11.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="tfABIRiba" maxWidth="80.0" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfCABRiba" maxWidth="80.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="ckSpeseBancarie" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="addebito spese bancarie (esenti art. 15 D.P.R. 633/72 e s.m.i.)" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                  <TextField fx:id="tfSpeseBancarie" maxWidth="80.0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Label minWidth="-Infinity" text="Spese bancarie" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <font>
                  <Font size="11.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            </GridPane>
            <Label text="Note" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="10">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Causale" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="10">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <TextArea fx:id="taNote" maxHeight="50.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
            <TextArea fx:id="taCausale" maxHeight="50.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
            <HBox spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnSpan="5" GridPane.rowIndex="12">
                <Label text="Voci fattura" />
                <Separator HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </HBox>
            <fx:include fx:id="tablePrestazioni" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" source="TablePrestazioni.fxml" GridPane.columnSpan="5" GridPane.rowIndex="13" />
            <Label text="Sezionale" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Emittente" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                <font>
                    <Font size="11.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
         <Label text="Ritenuta d'acconto" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
            <font>
               <Font size="11.0" />
            </font>
         </Label>
        </GridPane>
    </ScrollPane>
    <CheckBox fx:id="ckEmessa" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="emessa" />
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

When I try to open the dialog here is the result:

[image: Opened dialog]

```
Node cont = (Node) content;
cont.autosize();
dPane.setContent(cont);
```

I'm setting the computed size to pref width/height and max size to max width height of the dialogPane:

```
DialogPane dPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
dPane.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
dPane.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
dPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
dPane.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

And I'm also doing this part on the onShown event of the dialog

```
DialogPane dPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
Stage stage = (Stage) dPane.getScene().getWindow();
stage.sizeToScene();
dPane.autosize();
```

So is there a way to expand the dialog so all the fields are visible? I'd say something similar to `pack()` in swing.

I'm using java 11 with javafx (org.openjfx) 19-ea+3

For loading up the nodes I'm using FxWeaver

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you to anyone that could help me.

Comment: Create a small full JavaFX program without most of the other stuff that demos the issue.

Comment: This works fine for me, out of the box. (I omitted the FontAwesome stuff but I don't think that will make any difference.) Get rid of all the stuff you put in to try to fix it (such as the calls to `autosize()`, which are obviously just blind guesses). The Spring stuff is irrelevant. Create and post a [mre].

Comment: I suggest using modern Java and JavaFX versions (e.g. 21.0.2+) and not using early access (`ea` versioned) software.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your comments. It was a really stupid problem, I didn't remember to check the css. I had:

```
.dialog-pane {
  -fx-background-color: -color-bg-default;
  -fx-padding: 0;
  -fx-max-width: 600px;
}
```

So I just needed to remove the `-fx-max-width`

Thank you all.